# Is it possible to change the magento product image background color white instead of another gray color

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to change the magento2 product image background color white instead of another gray color.

can anyone know the answer . please help me to do this.

Comment: kindly find the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/lyuj14 instead of white background i want some another color

Answer (score 2):

First you need to overide `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php` in your local module.

In this file, there is background color declaration you need to change it

```
protected $_backgroundColor = [255, 255, 255];
```

After that run these commands:

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: kindly find the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/lyuj14 instead of white background i want some another color

Comment: if i am doing above your answer means , i will get like this https://prnt.sc/ocijff

Comment: I share the example color code `$_backgroundColor` variable. Have you change the value of `$_backgroundColor` variable with your own color code ? like replace the value with your color code

Comment: Yes changed the color code